# Authenticating on TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I'm having trouble authenticating as a specific user on MS Team Foundation Server. In older versions it would look like:

```
teamFoundationCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("<USERNAME>", "<PASSWORD>", "<DOMAIN>");

TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://mars:8080/", teamFoundationCredential);
```

Can some one tell me the equivilent for the 2010 version. So far I have:

```
ICredentialsProvider cred = null;

tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://asebeast.cpsc.ucalgar.ca:8080/tfs/DefualtCollection"));

tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

For TFS 2010, use the following:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
        new Uri("http://asebeast.cpsc.ucalgar.ca:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential("domain_name\\user_name", "pwd"));
collection.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Comment: Note this worked for me on a non-domain server if I removed the 'domain_par' section of the username.

Comment: also: you nay need NetworkCredential("username","password","domain") instead of NetworkCredential("username\\domain","password). It worked for me the first way, but not the second.

Comment: I think the correct syntax is... 

TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
new Uri(@"http://asebeast.cpsc.ucalgar.ca:8080/tfs/DefualtCollection"),
new System.Net.NetworkCredential("domain_name\\user_name", "pwd"));

Answer (score 4):

I've been having the same problem. The above solution doesn't work for me and really can't figure out why. I keep getting a cast exception.
Spent a day trying to figure this out - so thought I'd share my current workaround to the problem.
I've created my own internal class that implements ICredentialsProvider - as below:

```
private class MyCredentials : ICredentialsProvider
{
    private NetworkCredential credentials;
    #region ICredentialsProvider Members
    public MyCredentials(string user, string domain, string password)
    {
        credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);
    }

    public ICredentials GetCredentials(Uri uri, ICredentials failedCredentials)
    {
       return credentials;
    }

    public void NotifyCredentialsAuthenticated(Uri uri)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I then instantiate this and pass it in as below:

```
MyCredentials credentials = new MyCredentials(UserName, Password, Domain);
TfsTeamProjectCollection configurationServer =
    TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
        new Uri(tfsUri), credentials);
```

Note that I haven't implemented the NotifyCredentialsAuthenticated - not sure what this actually does, so left the NotImplementedException in there so I could catch when its called, which so far hasn't happened. Now successfully connected to TFS.

Comment: You might have needed to just do new NetworkCredential("username","password","domain") instead of NetworkCredential("username\\domain","password)

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems connecting to our old TFS 2008 server using this method as well, but the thing that solved my case was really simple:

First I defined the TFS Url to be:

```
private const string Tfs2008Url = @"http://servername:8080/tfs/";
static readonly Uri Tfs2008Uri = new Uri(Tfs2008Url);
```

The path used in the URL is the one we use when connecting via VisualStudio, so I thought this had to be the same in API calls, but when I tried to use this with the following authentication, I got a TF31002 / 404 error:

```
var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(Tfs2008Uri,new NetworkCredential("AdminUser","password","domain_name"));
collection.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

But when I changed the Url to the TFS root, it authenticated OK!

```
private const string Tfs2008Url = @"http://servername:8080/";
static readonly Uri Tfs2008Uri = new Uri(Tfs2008Url);
```

Don't know if that helped anyone, but it sure did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

This has worked pretty good for me:

```
_tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
_tfs.ClientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("myUserName", "qwerty_pwd", "myDomainName")));
_tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```